# Problem with the approve function of ERC20 token contract

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

So, whenever I am trying to approve my smart contract using the approve function of the ERC20 token contract the owner and the spender are being set the same.

```
function getValues(address _token) external {
       
        MyToken token = MyToken(0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138);
        token.approve(address(this),10);
                   
}
function transfer(address _token) external {
      MyToken token = MyToken(0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138);
    token.transferFrom(msg.sender,address(this),10);
}
```

The output to the code is coming something like this [
{
"from": "0xd9145CCE52D386f254917e481eB44e9943F39138",
"topic": "0x8c5be1e5ebec7d5bd14f71427d1e84f3dd0314c0f7b2291e5b200ac8c7c3b925",
"event": "Approval",
"args": {
"0": "0xf8e81D47203A594245E36C48e151709F0C19fBe8",
"1": "0xf8e81D47203A594245E36C48e151709F0C19fBe8",
"2": "10",
"owner": "0xf8e81D47203A594245E36C48e151709F0C19fBe8",
"spender": "0xf8e81D47203A594245E36C48e151709F0C19fBe8",
"value": "10"
}
}
]

Comment: What goal are you trying to achieve? To set the user (calling the `getValues()`) as the spender?

Comment: Actually, I was trying to make a staking contract where people can come and deposit a token and withdraw them accordingly...

Answer (score 0):

Calling approve inside the smart contract make the contract the msg.sender of the call to the approve function, what you are doing in get values is approving the contract to move the tokens the contract already owns, if you want to make an use to approve the contract to move the user tokens that call should be made by the user

Comment: So, in that case, if I want to move the tokens from the user to the smart contract in that case the user needs to get the smart contract approved by the token from their end...

Comment: the front end that interacts with your contract should have a way to let the user approve your contract to move the tokens